# Weird Registry found

Tags: malware

Found weird entries in Reg. What is this in my registry?[image]

Comment: Are you this guy? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/regedit-error-in-hkey-current-user/da7926b4-d61e-48ef-bb13-7ee3b2af280f?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be just corruption because the names don't look structured enough in my eyes. Either way you should definitely run a malware check on your system.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER is simply a link to the registry hive of the user that is currently logged on. To find this hive manually, navigate to HKEY_USERS and select the registry with your security identifier (SID) (to find out this go into command prompt and enter `wmic useraccount get name,sid` - it will be to the right of your username). Once in this registry hive, does it look the same as HKEY_CURRENT_USER? If not then it's most probably corruption. If it is the same then try logging in as a different user and checking HKEY_CURRENT_USER to see if the same, weird registries are there.

Even still, the there are no registries missing in your HKEY_CURRENT_USER that should be there, so I personally would just delete them.